# How do I enable CSV downloads and uploads in the GUI?

Tags: alan

In the GUI, I see a button for Excel downloads, but how do I enable CSV downloads and uploads in the GUI? [[image: place where I would like to see the button[1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings.alan for that client system you probably need to edit these lines:

`csv actions: enabled                    <-- set to enabled
system administrator role: 'Employee'   <-- set to your role`

The `csv actions` setting toggles the feature globally, the `role` settings restricts access to specific user groups.